# Решение задач с импликацией в ЕГЭ

Tags: алгоритм, математика, логика

Как правильно решить следующую задачу?

> Для какого из указанных значений Х истинно высказывание?

```
(x * (x - 8) > -25 + 2 * x) → (x > 7)

1) 4
2) 5
3) 6
4) 7
```

Я считаю, что в следствии при любом из вышеперечисленных вариантов `X` будет *ложь*.
Получается, что правильного ответа нет.

Comment: И что, что в следствии будет ложь? Импликация истинна тогда, когда из false следует false, так что второй вариант правильный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Импликация по сути означает: "*Из истинного утверждения не может следовать ложное*". Из ложного утверждения может следовать любое, из истинного - только истинное. Ситуация true → false единственная, когда выражение (импликация) ложно.

---

Эм.. Подставить и посчитать.

```
for (var x of [4, 5, 6, 7])
  if ((x * (x - 8) > -25 + 2 * x) <= (x > 7))
    console.log(x);
```

Ответ 5.

Импликацию заменил на `<=` в связи с особенностью bool'евских значений: true=1, false=0. Поскольку импликация ложна только в случае, когда слева true, а справа false, то можно заменить её на числовое сравнение `leftCondition <= rightCondition`.

---

Как вообще решать.

1. Импликация истинна, если справа true.
   Ни для одного из вариантов это условие не выполняется.
2. Если справа false, то надо чтобы слева тоже была false.
   x * (x - 8) > -25 + 2 * x должно быть ложно.

Значит

```
x * (x - 8) <= -25 + 2 * x
x^2 - 8*x <= -25 + 2*x
x^2 - 10*x + 25 <= 0
(x-5)^2 <= 0
x = 5
```

Comment: @nddd, ответ обновлён.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я просто запутался читая про импликацию в вики.

Answer (score 1):

Прикинул задачу [в математике](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%20*%20%28x%20-%208%29%20%3E%20-25%20%2B%202%20*%20x%29%20-%3E%20%28x%20%3E%207%29). В районе 5 ответ. Можешь просто вместе построить и посмотреть. Решить графическим методом.

Answer (score 1):

Заполняем пробелы в логике: **A → B** равносильно **(!A ) | B**.
Программа:

```
$test = array (4,5,6,7);
array_walk ($test, function($x){
    printf(
        "<br>x=%d condition = %s conclusuion = %s implication = %s", 
        $x, 
        ($cond = (($x * ($x - 8)) > (-25 + 2 * $x))) ? "ИСТИНА": "ЛОЖЬ &emsp;",
        ($conc = ($x>7)) ? "ИСТИНА": "ЛОЖЬ &emsp;",
        (!$cond | $conc)  ? "ИСТИНА": "ЛОЖЬ &emsp;"
    ); 
});
```

Результаты:

```
x=4 condition = ИСТИНА conclusuion = ЛОЖЬ   implication = ЛОЖЬ  
x=5 condition = ЛОЖЬ   conclusuion = ЛОЖЬ   implication = ИСТИНА
x=6 condition = ИСТИНА conclusuion = ЛОЖЬ   implication = ЛОЖЬ  
x=7 condition = ИСТИНА conclusuion = ЛОЖЬ   implication = ЛОЖЬ
```